# Methods with certain functions

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, functional-programming

Is there any way to write these two class methods, without using loops, lambda functions, and other additional functions? I only want to use the functions and functors from libraries algorithm and functional. I have tried to use  while loop and recursion to fugure something out, but still couldn't solve this. I didn't want to post the whole code since it is too long.

(I don't have to use these libraries for << operator, if there is a way to solve this without them, and min and max are lists)
My main goal is not using loops, lambda functions and any additional functions outside the two libraries. EraseNegativeTemperatures is the method which should only erase the registered pairs of temperatures where both of them are negative (I wrote the method in the part which I didn't post, and that method makes pairs where one temperature is from min and the other one from max)

Operator << outputs all the registered temperatures, the min ones in one row and the max ones in the second row; the temperatures in one row are separates by space.

```
void Temperatures::EraseNegativeTemperatures() {
  for (auto it = max.begin(); it != max.end(); it++) {
    if (*it < 0) {
      auto it1 = it;
      auto it2 = min.begin();
      while (it1 != max.begin()) {
        it2++;
        it1--;
      }
      min.erase(it2);
      it = max.erase(it);
    }
  }
  // std::remove_if(min.begin(), min.end(), std::bind(std::less<int>(),
            max.begin() + std::placeholders::_1 - min.begin(), 0));
}

// second method
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &flow, const Temperatures &t) {
  std::for_each(t.min.begin(), t.min.end(),
                [&flow](int x) { flow << x << " "; });
  flow << std::endl;
  std::for_each(t.max.begin(), t.max.end(),
                [&flow](int x) { flow << x << " "; });
  flow << std::endl;
  return flow;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to describe in text what the algorithm is trying to do. It's a bit confusing since it seems to be modifying both the `min` and `max` containers.

Comment: Your problem description is contradictory. You want to not use other functions, yet you want to use other functions (from certain libraries). Maybe you are asking if there is something from `<algorithm>` that will let you accomplish some goal in one line?

Comment: Considering your commented code: A lambda can be a bit simpler: `std::remove_if(max.begin(), max.end(), [](int value) { return value < 0; })` – but you need to follow [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: What is EraseNegativeTemperatures doing?

Comment: @BillLynch I edited the question and added the details about these two methods

Comment: @Surt I edited the question and added the details about these two methods

Comment: What data type are you using? Erasing again and again one single element on `std::vector` is as inefficient as can be. And in case of `std::vector`, you can profit from random access property of its iterator when calculating `it2`.

Comment: @Aconcagua min and max are the lists

Comment: You mean `std::list`?

Comment: If min and max belong together at any point of time, your design is questionable. It would be better to have a struct containing `min` and `max` members and one single list of these structs.

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't want to use lambda? For a second I thought you have pre-C++11, but then you used `std::bind`, which is only available after C++11. Plus you are totally fine using lambdas in your `<<` overload?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep It is just the requrement of this task, I have managed to respect this rule for all other methods except these two. No, I am not fine with using lambda in << overload, I am asking for help with it, too, I don't know how to solve it without lambda

Comment: If no for loops/additional functions, then would recursion be OK? By modifying these two you could call them with default argument with `min.begin()`. If the arguments are paired then you should be able to get one from the other. Unfortunately this requires an extra function for `operator<<`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you erase a temperature from each of min and max vector which are reverse of each other.

Added a test if the min temp is also negative.

Totally untested code

```
void Temperatures::EraseNegativeTemperatures() {
  for (auto it = max.begin(); it != max.end(); it++) {
    if (*it < 0) {
      auto diff = std::distance(max.begin(), it);
      
      if (*(min.rend()+diff) < 0) {
        min.erase(min.rend()+diff); // reverse of max
        it = max.erase(it);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to delete the pairs of temperatures where both of them are negative (the first member of the pair is from min and the second one is from max)

Comment: I have already created the method which would make these pairs

Comment: `it1` moves backwards until reaching begin, at the same time `it2` moves forwards – i. e. afterwards, `it2` will have the same offset into `min` as original `it` has into `max`. So removing pairs at the same offset in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

At first it might be simpler to erase from both lists separately; the following (disallowed) lambda solution will be the starting point:

```
auto current = max.begin();
min.erase(
    remove_if(
        min.begin(), min.end(),
        [&current] (int /* ignored! */) { return *current++ < 0; }
    ),
    min.end()
);
```

This will remove all those elements from the `min` list that have a corresponding negative value in the `max` list. Afterwards you can remove the negative values from the `max` list with an expression you have already found:

```
max.erase(
    remove_if(
        max.begin(), max.end(),
        std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 0)
    ),
    max.end()
);
```

The tricky part is now to re-build the lambda with standard library means only.

So we will need the operators above available as ordinary functions so that we can bind to them:

```
auto dereference = &std::list<int>::iterator::operator*;
auto postIncrement = static_cast<
        std::list<int>::iterator (std::list<int>::iterator::*)(int)
    >(
        &std::list<int>::iterator::operator++
    );
```

The `static_cast` for getting the second operator is necessary to distinguish the post-increment operator from the pre-increment operator.

Now we need to bind everything to the less-than operator:

```
auto lt0 = std::bind(
        std::less<int>(),
        std::bind(dereference, std::bind(postIncrement, std::ref(current), 0)),
        0
);
```

Note the creation of a reference to the iterator! The resulting functor we now can use to erase from `min` list:

```
min.erase(remove_if(min.begin(), min.end(), lt0), min.end());
```

Pretty similarly we can create the functor for outputting the arrays; at first we need the operators available; note that one of is a member function, the other one not:

```
auto outInt = static_cast<std::ostream& (std::ostream::*)(int)>(
    &std::ostream::operator<<
);
auto outChar = static_cast<std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&, char)>(
    &std::operator<<
);
```

Now we can again bind everything together:

```
auto out = std::bind(
    outChar,
    std::bind(outInt, std::ref(flow), std::placeholders::_1),
    ' '
);

std::for_each(t.min.begin(), t.min.end(), out);
flow << std::endl;
std::for_each(t.max.begin(), t.max.end(), out);
flow << std::endl;
```

Comment: I know how to solve this with while loop, but don't know how to solve this without it. I only want to use the functions or functors from libraries algorithm and functional, without loops or other functions

Comment: @Adrian Well, it worked, but was hopelessly ineffcient, thus the first iterating variant. Now added another version. I don't see another way of getting around custom code *entirely* than the redesign, as standard libraries algorithms are not designed to manage two parallel data structures.

Comment: This solution would be great if I could use the lambda functions, but I can't use them

Comment: @Adrian Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for functors. So you might write one explicitly if you are forced to work with pre-C++11 standard.

Comment: I know it, and I would be able to solve this by myself if there was not a rule for this task which says: no lambda function, loops or any other additional functions besides the ones from libraries algorithm and functional. As you could see, I have one lambda function for operator <<, but that is a problem because of this rule here. I have managed to respect this rule for all other methods except these two.

Comment: @Adrian Are you allowed to do the re-design? Then you are out of all the trouble... If not: Are you allowed to have *specialisations* of existing standard library templates?

Comment: None of that is allowed, I think that std::bind should be helpful with solving this, but I can't find the way

Comment: @Adrian OK, this has been a bit tricky. I didn't manage to re-create the removal in one go of the original lambda due to not being able to get an address of `operator=` for `int` (of course, not a function...), but that shouldn't matter...

Comment: Do you know anything for << because I can't find the way to get rid of the lambda function there, and is there any way not to use the std::mem_fn, maybe using std::ostream_iterator<int> coud be helpful. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Added - and yes, we can skip `std::mem_fn`, `std::bind` explicitly [allows pointers to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), did so in the answer already.

Comment: EraseNegativeTemperatures does not work properly. It doesn't erase the pairs with both negative temperatures

Comment: @Adrian Can you provide failing input? Then I can have another look at.